# i am unable to resolve the issue that the inner top-right boxes inside the three boxes do not stick properly to the top right corner

Tags: html, css

```css
 *{
     box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .header{
     text-align: center;
     margin: 40px;
     font-size: 30px;
    }
    p#id {
     border: 3px solid black;
     background-color: gray;
     width: 90%;
     height: 250px;
     font-size: 18px;
     color: #fff;
     padding-left: 12px;
     padding-top: 80px;
     padding-right: 12px;
     padding-bottom: 10px;
     margin: auto;
     margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
    .row {
     width: 100%;
    }
    .col-lg-3 .col-md-3, div.smbox{
     position: relative;
     float: right;
     width: 110px;
     height: 30px;
     margin-left: 497px;
     margin-right: 32px;
     background-color: white;
     border: 3px solid black;
    }
    .col-lg-3 .col-md-3, div.smbox, p#normal{
     text-align: right;
     padding: 0px 16px 60px 0px;
     background-color: burlywood;
     overflow: hidden;
    }
    @media (min-width: 992px) {
     .col-lg-3{
      float: left;
      }

     .col-lg-3{
      width: 33%;
      }
    }
    @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
     .col-md-3{
      float: left;
      }

     .col-md-3{
      width: 50%;
      }
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<h1 class="header">OUR MENU!</h1>
    <div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
    <div class="smbox"><p id="normal">HTML</p></div>
    <p id="id">ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam eum delectus atque nostrum impedit praesentium libero? Officia modi impedit perferendis architecto reiciendis commodi tenetur quia nam enim ipsum! Officia, delectus?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
    <div class="smbox"><p id="normal">CSS!</p></div> 
    <p id="id">ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem est totam nulla. Voluptatibus, quis ut voluptatem natus, eum explicabo, placeat voluptates accusantium sapiente reiciendis aliquam eos corporis et rem saepe?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
    <div class="smbox"><p id="normal">JavaS</p></div>
    <p id="id"> ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi necessitatibus, sit repellat aspernatur ratione consectetur maiores architecto adipisci asperiores quos nobis laboriosam voluptate, itaque perferendis eum eligendi dolorum saepe dicta.</p> 
    </div>
    </div>
```

The inner top-right boxes of every other box aren't staying at the top-right corner of the major box. During responsive test, they fail to do the same. I tried every other possibility but it feels like I am doing something wrong and that there is some issue with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you needed it that way? I made edits to css. Some padding rules have been removed and centering rules have been added. And the text in the block was centered correctly.

```css
*{
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.header{
 text-align: center;
 margin: 40px;
 font-size: 30px;
}
p#id {
 border: 3px solid black;
 background-color: gray;
 width: 90%;
 height: 250px;
 font-size: 18px;
 color: #fff;
 padding-left: 12px;
 padding-top: 80px;
 padding-right: 12px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 margin: auto;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.row {
 width: 100%;
}
.col-lg-3 .col-md-3, div.smbox{
 position: relative;
 float: right;
 width: 110px;
 /*height: 30px;*/ /*remove this it*/
 height: 100%; /*add this it*/
 /*margin-left: 497px;*/ /*remove this it*/
 /*margin-right: 32px;*/ /*remove this it*/
 margin-right: 5%; /*add this it*/
 background-color: white;
 border: 3px solid black;
}
.col-lg-3 .col-md-3, div.smbox, p#normal{
 text-align: center; /*add this it*/
 /*padding: 0px 16px 60px 0px;*/ /*remove this it*/
 /*background-color: burlywood;*/ /*remove this it*/
 overflow: hidden;
}

/*this is nth-child color*/

.row > div:nth-child(1) .smbox {
 background-color: burlywood;
}

.row > div:nth-child(2) .smbox {
 background-color: red;
}

.row > div:nth-child(3) .smbox {
 background-color: green;
}

/*--------------------------*/

@media (min-width: 992px) {
 .col-lg-3{
  float: left;
  }

 .col-lg-3{
  width: 33%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
 .col-md-3{
  float: left;
  }

 .col-md-3{
  width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1 class="header">OUR MENU!</h1>
  <div class="row"> 
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
  <div class="smbox"><p id="normal">HTML</p></div>
  <p id="id">ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam eum delectus atque nostrum impedit praesentium libero? Officia modi impedit perferendis architecto reiciendis commodi tenetur quia nam enim ipsum! Officia, delectus?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
  <div class="smbox"><p id="normal">CSS!</p></div> 
  <p id="id">ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem est totam nulla. Voluptatibus, quis ut voluptatem natus, eum explicabo, placeat voluptates accusantium sapiente reiciendis aliquam eos corporis et rem saepe?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
  <div class="smbox"><p id="normal">JavaS</p></div>
  <p id="id"> ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi necessitatibus, sit repellat aspernatur ratione consectetur maiores architecto adipisci asperiores quos nobis laboriosam voluptate, itaque perferendis eum eligendi dolorum saepe dicta.</p> 
  </div>
  </div>   
</body>

THE INNER TOP-RIGHT BOXES OF EVERY OTHER BOX AREN'T STAYING AT THE TOP-RIGHT CORNER OF THE MAJOR BOX. DURING RESPONSIVE TEST, THEY FAIL TO DO THE SAME. I TRIED EVERY OTHER POSSIBILITY BUT IT FEELS LIKE I AM DOING SOMETHING WRONG AND THAT THERE IS SOME ISSUE WITH THE CODE.
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!. That was the only problem I was facing in this code and you fixed it perfectly. thanks once again!!

Comment: no ploblem) if my answer helped you, then check the box to the left of my answer. thank)

Comment: DONE. but I just needed one small help. what changes do I make in CSS so that all the 3 inner boxes at the top right corner can have different background colors?

Comment: Thanks bro :-) In css, I marked everything that I added and deleted. If you have any questions, then contact us.

Comment: Do you want a different background color in this block - smbox?

Comment: NOT THAT, but the text like HTML CSS AND JAVAS are all having the same background color i.e  background-color: burlywood;  . and i just want different color for each of their background, would you be able to do that?

Comment: Yes, it can be done with the pseudo-class `:nth-child()`

Comment: i tried :nth-child(), but still color the color isn't changing from burlywood

Comment: I did as you wanted. Now every small block has its own color. Check please.

Comment: WOW!! IT'S PERFECT!! thanks once again, I was actually making changes in the p#normal selector because of which I wasn't able to change the rest of the box's background color

Comment: I forgot to say... In order for the `nth-child()` to be applied correctly, you need to delete this line `background-color: burlywood;` from the rule of `.col-lg-3 .col-md-3, div.smbox, p#normal {...}`. I was glad to help you!!! :-)